# Android doesn't find file

Tags: android

I've a file in my Download folder called random.txt and I want to display this in my android app. So I thought I could write this code to get the file path and open it:

```
String path= Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
        .toString() + File.separator;

openPdfIntent(path + "/Download/random.pdf");
```

But I get the log message that my file doesn't exist. If I browse to the location with my file manager the file is there.

My phone is a HTC one so I don't have a external sdcard.

Comment: File.separator + "/" ==> "//" isn't that your problem ? or you need to add "file:" in front of all of this for a local item

Comment: is your mobile connected with PC via cable while testing this code?

Comment: maybe need  "file://" + your_path + file_name ?

Comment: yes phone is connected.

Comment: disconnect phone and give a try...

Comment: Doesn't make a difference when the phone is disconnected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forgot to give permission in my manifest.

That in combination with

```
String  pdfFilePath =  Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
        .toString() + "/Download/random.pdf";
```

Comment: Jup thats why I checked it out. Thanks. To bad Android doesn't give me a warning about this. It just doens't do anything.

Comment: pls, vote up my comment, if you do not mind. Think so justice will prevail )

Answer (score 1):

Remove File.separator from 'path' variable.

Comment: Doesn't make a difference

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
pdfFilePath = "file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
        .toString() + "/Download/random.pdf";
```

Comment: Gives me this ST='file 'file:///storage/emulated/0/Download/random.pdf' not found'

Comment: @user1007522, hmm, you have permission for external storage ? Pls add this log to question.